# Sockets: client finding server automatically via name, not IP

Tags: c#, java, sockets, client

I got a client program in Java (Android app), and a server program in C#.
They communicate via Sockets over an internal network.

Problem: 

The client needs to have the server's IP address stored, to be able to connect. So, the server needs a static IP.

But now I got to a point I can't have a static IP anymore, so the client has to find the server when it starts up, somehow.

I thought you could use the computer-name to connect via Sockets, but that didn't work for me.
Then I had an idea to just do a broadcast with a basic request, and see who answers (the server from the correct IP), but I have no idea how I can do a broadcast and wait for multiple responses.
And then I also have to find the broadcast address.

Are there any techniques out there that I don't know and haven't come across yet?

Any help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: The technique you are looking for is called DNS lookup.

Comment: @dtb ... and DHCP ( for server publishing its dynamic address with the DNS server )

Comment: mDNS might also be of interest if it's a local network.

Comment: I tried DNS lookup, this one http://mowyourlawn.com/files/DomainRecord.java.txt and http://blogs.ethz.ch/windler/spingjava/dnslookupjava/ but they both seem to only work on hostnames from a DNS.

I need to find an IP based on a server's PC-name inside the same network, that doesn't got a webserver running or anything.

Comment: Ah damn, I thought InetAddress.getAllByName("pc_name"); was what I needed, but it doesn't work with pc-names. It just raises UnknownHostException instead. I've been looking and looking and almost everything either says this bit of code, or just use a pc-name in the socket constructor, but that totally doesn't work for me. :( This is driving me crazy...

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking is a hostname discovery service. JNDI is an API for discovering hostnames, but it is for java applications.

check [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56724t67%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) how to use JNDI from .NET framework

Comment: Isn't JNDI about classnames within an application? Or am I reading it wrong? Like the same functionality Activator.Create... does in .NET

Comment: You are correct - JNDI is more about "classnames" (more specifically, finding "services") and not really at all about "resolving hostnames to DNS".  DNS is what's called for (or the combination of DNS, DHCP and WINS over in Windows Land).